# Sorting columns in attribute tables in ArcGIS Pro 2.8

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, sorting

I have an attribute table whose columns I want to keep in chronological order, but when I try to drag and sort them, they return to their original order.

Is there a way to make them keep the order I put them in?

As well, is there a way to sort them automatically?

Additional information that might be relevant: these columns were added by intersecting using the geoprocessing tool Extract Multi Values to Points. This was done in multiple batches, one for each year.

[image]

Comment: [Sort (Data Management)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/sort.htm) is the tool to permanently sort a table.  It creates a new table, which, if edited, might no longer be in sorted order.

Comment: I have found that using the [Fields view](https://bit.ly/3ymkl7p) of the attribute table in ArcGIS Pro, as opposed to simply dragging columns, is much better a rearranging columns. This is (of course) only a temporary Layer setting, and doesn't permanently alter the field order of the underlying feature class. To permanently alter fields, have a look at [Feature-Class-to-Feature-Class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.7/tool-reference/conversion/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm) along with its [field mapping](https://bit.ly/3dALlI4) settings